# WPF - How to Enable disable button when a text box has text length is 6 in XAML only

Tags: wpf, button

WPF - How to Enable disable button when a text box has text length is 6 in XAML only.
Something like enable button if textbox.length == 6 else disable button.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in XAML only.  The closest you could get is to create an `IValueConverter` that can convert the number `6` in to the value `true`.  Then bind the `IsEnabled` property of the `Button` to `TextBox.Text.Length` using the converter.